# sql web replication ?diag errors

Tags: replication, iis-8, sql-server-2012

Trying to configure web replication, and running into a number of issues.

When running replisapi.dll?Diag, I receive the following errors:

```
CLSID_SQLReplErrors FAILED 0x80040154 

replrec.dll classes FAILED 0x80040154
```

I tried copying replrec.dll from the SQL Server to the IIS server and registering the DLL, but then the call to ?Diag hangs, and just says "Waiting" indefinitely.

I also tried using the Configure Web Replication Wizard on the publication, with no luck.

Server 2012 for both the DB server and IIS server
SQL Server 2012
IIS 8
SQL Connectivity Components are installed on the IIS server
SQL Management Studio is installed on the IIS server

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I was able to fix this problem by installing an instance of SQL Express and the replication components on the IIS Server.  I'm glad it fixed it, but that step isn't on any of the checklists, which all say just to install the Connectivity Components and Management Studio.  I'm going to leave the topic open for now, because I'm curious if there is a more appropriate fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by installing an instance of SQL Express and the replication components on the IIS Server. I'm glad it fixed it, but that step isn't on any of the checklists, which all say just to install the Connectivity Components and Management Studio.